# A short exact sequence with a locally finite group

Tags: group-theory

> If your group $G$ belongs to a short exact sequence $$1 \to F \to G \to \mathbb{Z}^2 \to 1,$$ where $F$ is a locally finite group, is it true that $G$ necessarily contains a copy of $\mathbb{Z}^2$?

If $F$ is finite, this is clearly true: If $a,b \in G$ lift a basis of $\mathbb{Z}^2$, then $[a,b^k] \in F$ for every $k \geq 1$, hence $[a,b^p]=[a,b^{p+q}]$ for some $p,q \geq 1$. We conclude that $[a,b^q]=1$, so that $\langle a,b^q \rangle$ defines a copy of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ in $G$.

Is it still true when $F$ is locally finite?

**EDIT:** A group is *locally finite* if its finitely-generated subgroups are finite.

Comment: First, $N=F$ in your argument. Second, it uses only the subgroup of $G$ generated by $a$ and $b$, hence, it works for $F$ locally finite.

Comment: But $a$ and $b$ does not belong to $F$. I use that $[a,b^k] \in N$ for every $k \geq 1$, but a priori the $[a,b^k]$'s does not belong to a finitely-generated subgroup.

Comment: Yes, you a right, of course. Incidentally, if $F$ is abelian then it is indeed enough to assume that $F$ is a torsion group. This follows from considering $H^2(Z^2, F)$.

Comment: @MoisheCohen, I'm not sure what you mean by $N$. Also, if your last comment is an asnwer to the question at hand, please would you post it as such in order to close the question? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turns out to be negative: Houghton's group $H_3$ is (locally finite)-by-$\mathbb{Z}^2$ but it does not contain $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

The $n$-th Houghton's group is defined as follows. Let $R_n$ denote the disjoint union of $n$ *rays* (ie., graphs whose vertices are the integers and whose edges link two consecutive integers). Then $H_n$ is the group of the bijections $R_n^{(0)} \to R_n^{(0)}$ which preserve the ends at infinity of $R_n$ and which preserve adjacency for all but finitely many pairs of vertices.

Any element of $H_n$ defines a translation on each ray (if you look at sufficiently far away), hence a morphism $H_n \to \mathbb{Z}^n$. However, in order to get a bijection, the sum of all the translation lengths must be zero. So the previous morphism provides a surjective morphism $H_n \to \mathbb{Z}^{n-1}$. The kernel of this morphism is included into the commutator subgroup of $H_n$, which coincides with the collection of the elements of $H_n$ which fix each ray sufficiently far away from their origins. So the commutator subgroup is isomorphic to $S_{\infty}$, the union of the symmetric groups $\bigcup\limits_{n \geq 1} S_n$. Consequently, we have the short exact sequence $$1 \to S_\infty \to H_n \to \mathbb{Z}^{n-1} \to 1.$$
The fact that $H_3$ does not contain $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is not obvious. It follows for instance from the article *Centralisers in Houghton's groups*, written by Simon St John-Green, which shows that the centraliser of an infinite-order element of $H_3$ must be virtually cyclic.

More generally, the greatest rank of a free abelian subgroup of $H_n$ is $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$.